# Converting a workstation to be server which os?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, hosting, operating-system

Firstly why im going to use a workstation as a server:
im broke and the choice was between a totally done/crap ancient server or a half decent hp workstation i chose the hp workstation with xeon(core2based) and a some fb-dimms.. for like 50 quid. I am putting a decent harddisk in it and will backup projects to my main pc.

**Primary purpose of the server =** well multipurpose i want to put databases run wcf services to them, perhaps host a website and lol maybe through the odd game server up, i realise ive mentioned alot of things but none of them will be that intensive they will all be small and not that intensive(wcf&database for my mobile phone apps).

Being a new grad means i can get my hands on almost anything Microsoft for free.(and no i dont want linux for this, its fine just being on my other :) computers)

**Right my question is which version of windows server would be best for me?**
i can get my hands on many verions but cant find an overview to tell me what there about
in web store were i get them MS does what they do best in describing a product by describing loads of stuff except what the hell it does.

Comment: I looked at your avatar and then it all made sense.

Answer (score 3):

[Overview of Windows Server Editions.](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-editions-overview.aspx)

As a student, you will appreciate that page. So. Much. Learninating.

Comment: +1 for the word learninating

Comment: thanks im a new grad and not in server tech nor networking, MS has an awful webstore that after a product description leaves with no notion of what you were reading does do ?? il remember to come back here for the vote downs :) cheers

Comment: @RY4N that just means you have learninating to do! Super User might be more of what you're looking for.